# Moving SQL Server database to production server causing login errors

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

First time doing this, so please be patient. I have a test server that contains Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server 2008 R2, and IIS. Thanks to everyone's help, my webpages were working perfectly. Now it's time to move everything to the production servers.

1. I imported the database to the production server using the SQL Import and Export Data utility - it was successful. One thing - testing server has SQL Server 2008 R2 and production server has SQL Server 2008.
2. I created a new user on the production server called `satime`. I gave this user all the same permissions as the original user. Enforce password policy, public and sysadmin for server roles, gave db_owner and public for database master, model, msdb, tempdb, and my database `TimeSQL`
3. In the database security, I gave this new user, `satime`, `db_owner` rights.
4. Changed all code in Visual Studio to go to new server.

   - Old server:

     ```
     DataSource=janetdev;Initial Catalog=TimeSQL;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=password
     ```
   - New Server

     ```
     Data Source=WillSQL;Initial Catalog=TimeSQL;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=satime;Password=password
     ```
5. Tried to debug webpage and I'm getting a login failed for user `satime`.

What did I miss doing? I double checked password, user settings.

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: The exact full error would be useful, and also can you verify that you can log into the `TimeSql` database using the `satime` user, and perform some of the query operations manually?

Comment: Can you login through a sql client utility (SSMS, OSQL, etc) with the same credentials?

Comment: Error says - Login failed for user 'satime'.    When I try to logon as satime, I'm getting an error - Login failed. Catalog information cannot be retrieved."  (I created a Data Link with server name willsql, added the username satime and password, clicked on Select the database, and the error pops up.)  Also, if I click OK, I get a Microsoft Data Link Error "Test Connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.  Login failed for user 'satime'.

Comment: I have retyped the password countless times, so I know it has to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

New server was set up for Windows Authentication mode only, not SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode.  Never even thought to check the server security.  Oh well!  Thanks for all your help!  You made me think.